# Matching coordinates with different sign in R

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, coordinates, stringr

I'm scraping a web map by downloading its html code and I want to extract coordinates of some points by matching regular expressions. I achieved extract the majority of coordinates with the following code:

```
library(stringr)    
unique(str_extract_all(doc,"\\[[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+[,][[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+\\]")[[1]])
```

This code extract cases where latitude is negative but it is sometimes negative. And I need especify symbol "[" to extract points but no boundaries of map. That is, I need obtain something like

```
[10.6302565,-74.9131161]
```

but I need include results like

```
[-10.6302565,-74.9131161]
```

I will be grateful with your help. Thanks.

**Aditional**

I also include `doc`. I this case I have positive latitude:

```
i<-"https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1YhVS6Z--LIc5k9rstJ24tYcb-Nc"
doc<-readLines(url(i))
doc<-doc[7]
doc<-iconv(doc,"latin1","ASCII","")
```

In this case, I have negative latitude:

```
i<-"https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1vq9uMa8L0PxnrhG-m3z3Jt-HDh4"
doc<-readLines(url(i))
doc<-doc[7]
doc<-iconv(doc,"latin1","ASCII","")
```

Comment: Please show few lines of `doc`

Comment: You mean you need to match an optional minus? [`"\\[-?\\d+[.]\\d+,-?\\d+[.]\\d+\\]"`](https://regex101.com/r/DhR7SS/1)?

Comment: Wiktor yes, with `-?` it work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
"\\[-?\\d+[.]\\d+,-?\\d+[.]\\d+\\]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhR7SS/1). Note that the `-?` (that matches 1 or 0 minus symbols) added after `\\[` and the `[[:punct:]]` replaced with `-?` after `,`. I also removed unnecessary escape symbols.

```
> library(stringr)    
> i<-"https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1YhVS6Z--LIc5k9rstJ24tYcb-Nc"
> doc<-readLines(url(i))
> doc<-doc[7]
> unique(str_extract_all(doc,"\\[-?\\d+[.]\\d+,-?\\d+[.]\\d+\\]")[[1]])
[1] "[10.6302565,-74.9131161]" "[10.8632551,-74.7769001]"
[3] "[10.9827508,-74.783735]"  "[10.9419975,-74.7826532]"
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).